# EarlGrey Failure - "Keyboard did not disappear after resigning first responder status"

Tags: ios, ui-testing, earlgrey

I am attempting to write UI tests for my login page.  The page has some intro animations, a search field (for finding the right server to connect to), and then once they select the right server, a username and password field appears.

Here's my test so far:

```
[[EarlGrey selectElementWithMatcher:grey_accessibilityID(@"searchTextField")]
 assertWithMatcher:grey_sufficientlyVisible()];
[[EarlGrey selectElementWithMatcher:grey_accessibilityID(@"searchTextField")] performAction:grey_typeText(@"gtX9Vn23k1")];
[[EarlGrey selectElementWithMatcher:grey_anyOf([self matcherForUITableViewCell], nil)] performAction:grey_tap()];

[[[EarlGrey selectElementWithMatcher:grey_accessibilityID(@"usernameTextField")]
 assertWithMatcher:grey_interactable()] performAction:grey_tap()];
[[[EarlGrey selectElementWithMatcher:grey_accessibilityID(@"usernameTextField")]
  assertWithMatcher:grey_interactable()] performAction:[GREYActions actionForTypeText:@"Why isnt this working?"]];
```

This test fails.

EarlGrey correctly selects, and types into the first text field (searchTextField).

EarlGrey correctly selects the tableview cell!

EarlGrey then correctly selects the usernameTextField, but then **fails** to type text, giving the following error after a timeout:

```
Exception: ActionFailedException
Reason: Action 'Type "Why isnt this working"' failed.
Element matcher: (respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) &&   accessibilityID("usernameTextField"))
Complete Error: Error Domain=com.google.earlgrey.ElementInteractionErrorDomain   Code=1 "Keyboard did not disappear after resigning first responder status of   <GHDLoginTextField: 0x7fa96a616bd0; baseClass = UITextField; frame = (150 387; 468    29); text = ''; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tintColor = UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fa96a55d5d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa96a616a80>>" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Keyboard did not disappear after resigning first responder status of <GHDLoginTextField: 0x7fa96a616bd0; baseClass = UITextField; frame = (150 387; 468 29); text = ''; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tintColor = UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fa96a55d5d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa96a616a80>>}
```

**"Keyboard did not disappear after resigning first responder status of "**

Anyone know what's going on here?  Strangely, btw, it looks like EarlGrey selects the next field (Password field) right before it errors out.  I have no UI code in there to select the password field at all.

**UPDATE:** I am using return key type "Next" on this text field, so that when a user taps the return key, I will take them to the next field (the password field). To do this, when the Next key is hit, I resign firstResponder on that text field, and call "becomeFirstResponder" on the password field.

This is causing EarlGray to error out, because if I remove the "resignFirstResponder" call, then it correctly types my text. The question is: WHY IS IT HITTING THE "Next" key when I am not telling it to!?

Comment: Is the autocorrect still on for keyboard when it fails to type? EarlGrey has a behavior where if it finds that Autocorrect is turned on, then it resigns the first responder, turns off autocorrect from the textfield and then returns back. TTBOMK, this is currently being modified.

Comment: Correction & Spell Check are both off. Keyboard type is default.  Appearance is "Default" Return key is "Next" (which takes user from the username field, to the password field).

Comment: The statement "[[[EarlGrey selectElementWithMatcher:grey_accessibilityID(@"usernameTextField")]
 assertWithMatcher:grey_interactable()] performAction:grey_tap()];" seems to be a bit redundant since the typeText following it should do all these checks as well. Could you remove this and check?

Comment: I agree it is redundant.  I didn't have that there originally, and it was failing.  I have since removed it, and verified again that it is still failing.

Comment: UPDATE:

I am using return key type "Next" on this text field, so that when a user taps the return key, I will take them to the next field (the password field).

To do this, when the Next key is hit, I resign firstResponder on that text field, and call "becomeFirstResponder" on the password field.

This is causing EarlGray to error out, because if I remove the "resignFirstResponder" call, then it correctly types my text.  

The question is:  WHY IS IT HITTING THE "Next" key when I am not telling it to!?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in the EarlGray source.  Line 182 in GREYActions.m

```
// If the view already is the first responder and had autocorrect enabled, it must
  // resign and become first responder for the autocorrect type change to take effect.
  [firstResponder resignFirstResponder];
```

There is no check in place to determine if the view previously had autocorrect enabled.  So, ALL textfields will call "resignFirstResponder".  This is problematic for setups like mine, where resigningFirstResponder then passes firstResponder status to another textfield.

Comment: You should open a github issue for this for them https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/issues

Comment: the issue seems to have been updated. This this solve your problem?